# Can I preserve phone battery remotely?

Tags: battery

I lost my phone and connected it to my computer via Google account so I can check it's location, commend it to beep, etc. However, I will be able to retrieve it only tomorrow and by then it will definitely be drain out of battery as it has only 15% of battery capacity as of now. Can I turn it off and then on? Thanks.

Comment: no you can't. but you can remotely wipe the entire device (all data lost)

Comment: OK not what I wanted to hear, but thanks buddy.

Comment: wait for somebody has charged it

Comment: he he if he won't covet it for himself. I offered 75$ for the returner in n a notification I sent to the phone lock screen remotely. Should I raise it? (it is a galaxy s9).